# Transcode videos with queue

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I want to transcode videos that are uploaded to a directory in a server with a queue.
How can I order the server to encode a video using FFmpeg with Python? And how a queue system can be added above that?

Comment: What did you try? Where is your code showing the attempt?

Comment: That's the reason I posted a question here. I want someone to set me on the way with an 'idea', and then I'll try to implement it in code.

Comment: Sounds like you already have the idea (file->queue->encoder). What part of the _code_ do you need help with?

Comment: My biggest problem with the code right now is the part of the queue. I never did this sort of files queue and I don't know where I should start.

Comment: Write a daemon that keeps track of the directory you're dropping files into.  When a file is added, have the daemon add the file to a queue.  You can use a Python list for this purpose, or there's also a queue module in the standard library.  The subprocess module in the standard library will give you a way to send shell style commands to ffmpeg.  Reading the documentation for the standard library will probably be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at Celery distributed task queueing system? I use it in the quitd same project as yours.

Sultan